# How to download images from FTP to local folder using WinSCP command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, winscp

I am trying to use the WinSCP command line to access an FTP Server. Then download all JPEG's in the root folder and download them to a local folder on my C: drive.

Example of my script below.

```
>"C:/Program Files (x86)/winscp/winscp.exe" /open ftp://hostname;password@ipaddress/
```

This opens the connection but when I try to download all the images from the root folder using this.

```
>get /*.jpg
```

It times out.
Is there a better way to connect and get all images available?

Ideally I will put this in a batch file eventually when it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a batch file (e.g. `download.bat`) like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" ^
    /ini=nul /log=C:\writable\path\to\winscp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://hostname:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "get /*.jpg C:\local\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

Some references:

- [WinSCP command-line switches for scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting).
- [Automating file transfers from FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

You can even have [WinSCP generate the script/batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
get *.jpg
```

or

```
get -filemask=*.jpg -resumesupport=on *
```

More examples here:http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get